# Limit without l'hopital $\lim_{x \to 0} \left ( \frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right )$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the limit without L'hopital's rule and without  Taylor series:
$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left ( \frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right )
$

Is it possible?

Hints are more than welcome! 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.   You will probably need to use the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$

Comment: strictly speaking you cant evaluate this limit without knowing that $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ or without using it analytic properties, what can be seen as it Taylor series or not, depending on the context. In some books you learn this definition before to know what a derivative or a Taylor series is.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Here is a hint: Use the definition/well known formula $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) ^{n} $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x-1} = \frac{e^x-1-x}{(x)(e^x-1)}$

This, in turn, can be written as: $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \times \frac{x}{e^x-1}$

I do believe you need to know that $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ tends to $1$ and $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x-\frac1{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\frac x{e^x-1}}x.$$Now, since$$\frac{e^x-1}x=1+\frac x2+O(x^2),$$you have$$\frac x{e^x-1}=1-\frac x2+O(x^2)$$and therefore$$1-\frac x{e^x-1}=\frac x2+O(x^2).$$Therefore, your limit is $\frac12$.

Comment: Just fyi: question also states (in the body, not the title) that it's to be done without taylor series

Comment: What I did use was the fact that the Taylor polynomial of order $2$ of the exponential function at $0$ is $1+x+\frac{x^2}2$. This can be proved without even knowing what a series is.

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite the expression in the limit as follows 
$$ \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x-1} = \frac{e^x - 1 - x}{xe^x - x} $$
Using the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, which we recall is 
$$ e^x = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} \ , $$ 
we further rewrite the numerator and denominator as
$$ e^x - 1 - x = \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O} (x^3) = x^2(\frac{1}{2} +  \mathcal{O} (x) )\\ xe^x - x = x^2 + \mathcal{O} (x^3) =  x^2( 1 + \mathcal{O}(x) ) $$
where $ \mathcal{O} (x^3) $ denotes the terms of order higher then $2$ in the variable $x$. Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \mathcal{O}(x) = 0$ we can compute, using the theorem for product of limits, in the following manner
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x-1} ) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (\frac{e^x - 1 - x}{xe^x - x} ) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2(\frac{1}{2} +  \mathcal{O} (x) )}{x^2(1 +  \mathcal{O} (x) )} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2} +  \mathcal{O} (x)}{1 +  \mathcal{O} (x)} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Oh, sorry guys, I have missed the requirement not to use the Taylor expansion :-D